# MYSQL Total required for Query

Tags: mysql, count

Hi I am looking for a solution to my inability to understand how I can get an overall total for a column in my query.

This query gets engineers names and the number of jobs they have that are out of SLA i.e. the data the job should have been completed has past and the job has still to be completed.

```
SELECT Engineer,Job_Status,COUNT(*) as 'Out Of SLA' 
FROM import 
WHERE (Job_Status = 'P' or Job_Status='P2' or Job_Status='P8') 
      and (isnull(Job_Completed_Date) 
           or Job_Completed_Date='0000-00-00') 
           and (Job_SLA_Due_Date < CURDATE()
          ) 
GROUP BY import.Engineer,Job_Status
```

The code above produces the following results from the import table.

```
+----------------+------------+------------+
|    Engineer    | Job_Status | Out of SLA |
+----------------+------------+------------+
| Andy Beeres    | P          |         15 |
| Andy Broad     | P          |          4 |
| Darren Goodwin | P          |          6 |
+----------------+------------+------------+
```

I want to be able to show the **total** number of the Out of SLA column as well as the rest of the table data if that makes sense something like the table below.

```
| Engineer      | Job_Status    | Out of SLA    |
|-------------  |------------   |------------   |
| Andy Beeres   |      P        |         14    |
|               |     P2        |          3    |
|               |     P8        |          1    |
| Total         |               |         18    |
| Andy Broad    | P             |         12    |
|               | P2            |          2    |
| Total         |               |         14    |
| Grand Total   |               |         32    |
```

Regards

Alan

Comment: `as well as the rest of the table data if that makes sense` ... it only makes sense to show the columns by which you are grouping, aggregates, or non correlated subqueries.  Maybe you can show us what output you really want.

Answer (score 2):

Use `with rollup` with group by to get total_sla

According to [MySql Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html):

> The GROUP BY clause permits a WITH ROLLUP modifier that causes summary output to include extra rows that represent higher-level (that is, super-aggregate) summary operations. ROLLUP thus enables you to answer questions at multiple levels of analysis with a single query.

```
SELECT Engineer,Job_Status,COUNT(*) as 'Out Of SLA' 
FROM import 
WHERE (Job_Status = 'P' or Job_Status='P2' or Job_Status='P8') 
  and (isnull(Job_Completed_Date) 
       or Job_Completed_Date='0000-00-00') 
       and (Job_SLA_Due_Date < CURDATE()
      ) 
GROUP BY import.Engineer,Job_Status WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Hi I have updated my original question, if you could take a look I would appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

One option is to use a subquery which finds the SLA total:

```
SELECT Engineer,
       Job_Status,
       COUNT(*) AS `Out Of SLA`,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM import) AS total_sla
FROM import
WHERE (Job_Status = 'P' OR Job_Status='P2' OR Job_Status='P8') AND
      (ISNULL(Job_Completed_Date) OR Job_Completed_Date = '0000-00-00') AND
      Job_SLA_Due_Date < CURDATE()
GROUP BY Engineer,
         Job_Status
```

Comment: That's not what the OP is looking for. `total_sla` should be total of the last column.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz You're mistaken.  The `SLA` column is the count for each group.  Hence, the total across the table is then the count of the entire table.  But maybe my answer is wrong, if the OP also wants something else.